# I want to get the min and max temp but only for each date in the array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filtering

I am using the openweathermap API to get the 5 day 3 hour forecast. But I don't want to get data for every 3 hours. Just the max and min temp for each day to render.

I have managed to use map to display an array of objects showing the min and max temps relative to the date. But I want to whittle this down to just one result per day with the min and max displayed.

```
componentDidMount() {
        const apiKey = secrets.apiKey;
        axios
            .get(
                `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=berlin&APPID=${apiKey}&units=metric`
            )
            .then(data => {
                console.log("Current", data.data);
                this.setState({
                    result: data.data
                });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("err in api get", err);
            });
        axios
            .get(
                `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=berlin&APPID=${apiKey}&units=metric`
            )
            .then(data => {
                console.log("Forecast", data.data);
                this.setState({
                    forecast: data.data
                });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("err in api get", err);
            });
    }
    render() {
        if (!this.state.forecast) {
            return null;
        } else {
            const allDays = this.state.forecast.list;
            const newArr = allDays.map(forecast => {
                const container = {};
                container.date = forecast.dt_txt.slice(0, 10);
                container.temp_max = forecast.main.temp_max;
                container.temp_min = forecast.main.temp_min;
                return container;
            });
            console.log("newArr", newArr);

        }

        return (
            <div>
                <Current weather={this.state.result} />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: A [mcve] would be: Some sample data from that API, and the expected result, and your code towards solving this. How you load the stuff from the API is irrelevant for the question itself (unless someone knows an endpoint that directly returns the wanted data)

Comment: No types in comments, no propTypes - this code looks very mysterious